# How to bundle as single file in Rollup.js

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

In the [REPL on the Rollup site](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=0.45.2&shareable=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), the output shows that the imports are injected straight into the output file. On my computer, I'm unable to reproduce this (desired) behavior. Instead, my output file has `require('./my-other-file')` statements in it.

My entry file looks like this:

```
// entry.js

import { encode64 } from './utils';

export function myFunction() {
    return encode64('test');
}
```

My output file looks like this:

```
// bundle.js

(function () {
    'use strict';

    exports.__esModule = true;
    var utils_1 = require("./utils"); // <- don't want this
    function myFunction() {
        return utils_1.encode64('test');
    }
    exports.myFunction = myFunction;

}());
```

With a Rollup config file that looks like this:

```
export default {
    entry: 'entry.js',
    dest: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
};
```

How do I get my `encode64` import injected into the output file, rather than `require`d?

I need this in the browser and I don't want to use Browserify or other similar tools.

Comment: Do you have a `utils.js` file next to your `entry.js` file?

Comment: Yes, same directory. @RichHarris

Comment: Then something very strange indeed is happening. Can you create a minimal reproduction please?